# How to pass an enum value to a function?

Tags: enums, rust, arguments

I have several enums:

```
enum Foo {
    A(A),
    B(B)
}

enum A {
    C(i32),
    D(i32)
}

enum B {
    E(i32),
    F(i32)
}
```

How could I write a function that takes a `Foo` and checks if it is, say, a `B::E`, then returns an `Option<Foo>`?

Edit: for clarification, the enum value is passed as an argument. I tried doing it with a signature of `f(value: Foo, expected: Foo)` but I'm not sure how to call that, as (with `B::E` again) the compiler wants an i32 supplied.

Comment: This is pretty much day one of learning Rust. I suggest you read [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) before you go any further or else you are going to be constantly needing to ask these simple questions, which are not useful to anyone else coming to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry, didn't clarify what I meant.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do, and the error you are getting. The way it is now, people just have to kind of guess at what you're attempting.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with a function, because function parameters must be complete values and the way you would express "variant E of enumeration B" is with a pattern. But you can do it with a macro, which can take patterns as arguments.

First here is how you would do it with a fixed pattern in a function:

```
fn filter_e (x: Foo) -> Option<Foo> {
    match x {
        Foo::B (B::E (_)) => Some (x),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

Now if we want to make the pattern into a parameter, we need to wrap this code in a macro:

```
macro_rules! filter_foo {
    ($x:expr, $p:pat) => {{
        let x = $x;
        match x {
            $p => Some (x),
            _ => None,
        }
    }}
}
```

Which you then call like this:

```
filter_foo!(x, Foo::B (B::E (_)))
```

For more details on macros, see [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers the problem you're having, but you can use a match expression:

```rust
fn my_function(f: Foo) -> Option<Foo> {
    match f {
        Foo::B(B::E(_)) => { /* your code */ }
        _ => None // otherwise, return None
    }
}
```